# Getting the same memory again and again

Tags: c++, vector

In my program I am creating an object of a class in a loop and storing it in a vector. Then I print the address  of the object and the member variable. After that I erase them . I see that every time I see the same address assigned to my object and the member variable which is a pointer. Can any one explain this behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct csock {
unsigned int _refCount;
mutable pthread_mutex_t _pdata_mutex;
pthread_attr_t attr;
bool _bSocketClosed;            /// used for testing while closing the socket
int _iSockFD;                   /// Holds the native socket descriptor
void* _pfnArgs; 
void* _logger;                  /// For debug logging
bool _isServiceRunning; 
pthread_t _thread_id;           /// Thread id for the listener service
int _pipes[2];                  /// For stop signal communication
pthread_mutex_t* _countMutex;
unsigned long  _idleTimeOut;                //Idle Time Out
FILE* fp;
} __attribute__((packed)) csock_t;




class csocket
{
protected:
void* _pImpl;

public :

csocket(){
csock_t* ps = new csock_t;
this->_pImpl = reinterpret_cast<void*> (ps);
std::cout<<"\n ps is "<<ps <<" _pImpl is "<<_pImpl <<endl;
}
void* getImpl()
{
    return _pImpl;
}
};


int main ()
{

vector<csocket> v;

 for (int i=0; i< 5; ++i) {
    v.push_back(csocket());
    cout<<"\n after pushback "<<v[v.size()-1].getImpl();
    cout<<"\n after pushback object is"<<&(v[v.size()-1]);
    delete (csock_t*) v[0].getImpl();
    v.erase(v.begin()+0);
}
cout <<"\n size of vector is "<<v.size();
return 0;
}
```

I am adding the output in my system

```
ps is 0x8368008 _pImpl is 0x8368008
after pushback 0x8368008
after pushback object is0x8368078

ps is 0x8368008 _pImpl is 0x8368008
after pushback 0x8368008
after pushback object is0x8368078

ps is 0x8368008 _pImpl is 0x8368008
after pushback 0x8368008
after pushback object is0x8368078

ps is 0x8368008 _pImpl is 0x8368008
after pushback 0x8368008
after pushback object is0x8368078

ps is 0x8368008 _pImpl is 0x8368008
after pushback 0x8368008
after pushback object is0x8368078
```

Comment: There is no reason you couldn't be handed back the same address for a new object of the same type as the one just deleted. What behaviour did you expect to see?

Comment: To be frank my problem is much bigger. I think a shared pointer will solve my problem. I maintain a vector of tcp connection object. I delete these from vector once they are no longer needed. but the vector is under a mutex, so by the time i delete and remove it from the vector an another object with same address is created and added to the vector. My criteria of deletion was based on the address of the object, so now in the vector I have two objects with same address one which is dead and another which was newly created. This was causing me untimely crashes.

Comment: you have done it wrong. you have to change your deletion criteria /or/ don't remove any object when running the deletion(?) code.... or, use smart pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is storage based on a weak pointer. Your
vector stores weak pointers to the connection objects. Your main application
gets the shared pointers. The destructor for your connection object frees the
resource. Periodically you can pack the vector by erasing all weak pointers
with a use_count of zero.

```
class Connect;

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connect> ConnectPtr;
typedef boost::weak_ptr<Connect> ConnectWeakPtr;
typedef std::vector<ConnectWeakPtr> ConnectVector;

ConnectVector vector;

ConnectPtr ptr( new Connect ( ... ));

vector.push_back(ptr);

void pack() {
    ConnectVector tmp;
    BOOST_FOREACH(ConnectWeakPtr const & p, mMap){
        if (p.use_count() > 0){
            tmp.insert(p);
        }
        mMap.swap(tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After you `delete` the object the memory it previously occpied is marked as free and its ownership is passed to the heap, so the heap is allowed to reuse the space it occupied for future allocations. So it just happens that the heap reuses exactly the same memory block.

Comment: Ok so you all feel this is normal then thanks a lot  for the quick answers.

Answer (score 1):

Once an object is deleted, the memory it occupied is handed back to the runtime (or to the OS, in some cases) for reuse.  If you go and allocate memory for another object of exactly the same size, or sometimes even a little bit smaller, that chunk of memory is probably the best fit -- so it's quite reasonable to use that chunk of memory instead of carving another chunk out from somewhere else and raising the chance of memory fragmentation issues later on.

Comment: Ok, I knew the heap would re use it but I did not expect it to happen so soon, I expected a small gap before the same address is reused.

Comment: Sometimes there's a gap, sometimes there isn't.  Depends on the allocator used, what's been created and deleted up to that point, and a few other things.  But once you delete something, in C and C++, its memory is *immediately* handed back to the runtime and is immediately eligible for reuse.  Whether it's actually reused immediately is up to the allocator.